# i want to load 2 different pages on website . pages must change after reloading

Tags: php

i have tried to solve this problem via php . i can reload different pages for different browsers but i cant what i really want

my website is one page website [like that](http://www.pianotiles.org//)

i have one page html website which have 5-8 impression per visitor

i want to make another html page .

when user visits website at first i  want to load page 1 . on him second visit i want to load second page...

how can i do that??
also i want to load pages by %
i want to load page one 30% page two 70%...

please help..

Comment: So wait do you want random or every other visit?

Answer (score 2):

To load the pages by a percentage, you can generate a random number between 1 and 100 and decide from that, which page to deliver:

```
if (mt_rand(1, 100) <= 30) {
    // deliver page1 in 30%
    readfile('page1.htm');
} else {
    // deliver page2 in 70%
    readfile('page2.htm');
}
```

To load the pages alternating you could use a session variable to save the last displayed page.

```
session_start(); // init session
if (!isset($_SESSION['show_second'])) $_SESSION['show_second'] = false; // init session var

if (!$_SESSION['show_second']) {
    // deliver page1
    readfile('page1.htm');
} else {
    // deliver page2
    readfile('page2.htm');
}

$_SESSION['show_second'] = !$_SESSION['show_second']; // change value of session var for next hit
```